# Unexpected [ When Defining Array Inside A Loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to define an array inside of a loop so that it defines an item in the array as it increments. I am also trying to set the array item to another array item. However, I've tried multiple formats and I keep getting *Unexpected Token [*

```js
  var filename = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (span.innerHTML = ""; i < files.length; i++) {
    span.innerHTML += files[i].name + " <input type='text' name='" + type + i + "' placeholder='Display Name' onchange='aupdate(undefined)'>" + "<br>";
    var filename[i] = files[i].name;
  }
```

Comment: Remove `var` before `filename[i] = files[i].name;`. You don't want to declare a new variable here (and variable names cannot contain `[`).

Comment: Off-topic, but setting `span.innerHTML = ""` in the first space of the for loop looks very error prone. If you don't need to define anything just leave it blank and set the span in the previous line. e.g: `span.innerHTML = ""; for(;i < files.length; i++) ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare a new variable - and variables names cannot contain `[` or `]` (only the alphabet, numbers, `_` and `$`):

```
  var filename = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (span.innerHTML = ""; i < files.length; i++) {
    span.innerHTML += files[i].name + " <input type='text' name='" + type + i + "' placeholder='Display Name' onchange='aupdate(undefined)'>" + "<br>";
    filename[i] = files[i].name;
  }
```